# Possible to enable "strict mode" in FireBug and Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, console, strict-mode

With this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        var foo = 2;
        delete foo;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Firebug console gives:

```
applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is deprecated
>>> foo
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
foo
```

But then this is successful:

```
>>> var bar = 2;
undefined
>>> delete bar;
true
```

Even if you comment out `delete foo;` so that the script does not break, deleting `bar` is still successful despite the fact it "is a property of a Global object as it is created via variable declaration and so has [DontDelete attribute](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes)":

```
>>> foo
2
>>> delete foo
false
>>> var bar = 2;
undefined
>>> delete bar
true
```

Is it possible to enable "strict mode" in FireBug and or Chrome's console?

Comment: I wonder if the console code is being piped through `eval()`, in which case the DontDelete attributes won't be set.

Comment: ...right, if I had just read then next section: `And this is the gist of Firebug’s abnormal behavior. All the text in console seems to be parsed and executed as Eval code, not as a Global or Function one.`

Comment: I followed @zoranc's first suggestion just so I could see strict mode working in chrome's console.
`(function f() {
  'use strict';
  console.log('"this" here is: ', this, 'Strict Mode is cool...');
} ());`
`(function f() {
  console.log('"this" here is: ', this, 'Global variables are evil! So Crockford told me...');
} ());`

Comment: devtools console should really have a checkbox to enable strict mode for all commands

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The firebug console works by wrapping all the code in an "eval" call so the first statement in your script is no longer "use strict" - hence it is disabled. You could try wrapping your code in a function to enforce "use strict" for that particular function but the best solution I know of is to skip the console and test straight in the page itself.

Answer (score 7):

use shift+enter to input 'use strict'

like this 
[image]

Comment: It works. just need to make sure to add 'use strict'; at each interaction in F12 Chrome Console.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just testing a single function in the console, you can also just put 'use strict' as the first line in the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome: put `'use strict';` prefix in your code line (and/or shift+enter for multiline)

```js
'use strict'; var foo = 2; delete foo;
```

Answer (score -2):

On Chrome go to "chrome://flags", then "Enable Experimental JavaScript". Relaunch.

Comment: This is not correct. The flag enables the usage of the newest ES features.