# How can i use ES6 syntax such as let in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write some **ES6** code in chrome console but i ran with some errors. How can i run the **ES6** scripts in console?

For example, given the input

```
let type='grizzle';
```

the console records a `SyntaxError` with the message

> Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

as shown in the following screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Chrome console response]

Comment: This was marked as duplicate to a question about strict mode. However, strict mode (which is an ES5 feature) has nothing to do with ES6 so I'm reopening.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24011617/4361297

Comment: @slebetman the ES6 declarations `let` and `const` behave differently in strict mode, so it is actually relevant.

Comment: @OP in the future, please consider typing the code and exception details in question, rather than posting a screenshot

Comment: @saadq your suggested duplicate actually covers *enabling* ES6 features in Chrome, but in Chrome 45 the `let` declaration (which OP is using) is now enabled by default. OP's issue is different: the javascript block needs to be in strict mode.

Comment: @Jeremy If the OP's problem is really different, then show us by editing it to emphasize how it's different? From where I'm sitting it's a duplicate of the post I closed it as a duplicate of.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker there's some very strange confusing things going on here. OP's problem is *similar* to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369328/, which is "how do I use 'use strict' in JS console", and marking it as a duplicate of *that* might be fair. The question is **NOT** a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008366/, which is "how do I get Chrome to support ES6". Chrome v45 already supports ES6, so the current "duplicate" marking is totally irrelevant. If I edit the question to emphasise that, I will make the question worse.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker nonetheless I will give it a go, and you or someone else can knock back the edit if you wish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of late 2019, you can just use `let` in the console.

---

As the error message states, some ES6 features are not available outside of strict mode. Therefore, to take advantage of those features, you must first create a strict-mode block.

From the console, the easiest way to use strict mode is [by creating an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369328/how-to-use-strict-mode-in-chrome-javascript-console). For example,

```
(function() { "use strict"; let x = "asdf"; }());
```

will behave as intended when entered in the console.

Comment: You actually don't need 'use strict' for let. An arrow IIFE. `(() => {let a = "Hello world"; console.log(a)})()`

Comment: @ZenBoat thanks for pointing that out — seems like whatever restriction they had back in the day, they've now removed.