# "this" in global functions

Tags: javascript, this

I was under the impression that the "this" keyword represents the current owner that is in scope. Obviously, this is wrong. Let me get to the code:

```
alert(this);     // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay

function p1() {
    alert(this);
}

var p2 = function() {
    alert(this);
}

p1();           // alerts as undefined  -- ???
p2();           // alerts as undefined  -- ??
window.p1();    // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay
window.p2();    // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay
```

The code above first alerts [object Window], as I would expect but then the next two calls to p1() and p2() alert "this" as "undefined". The final two calls to p1() and p2() alert "this" as [object Window].

Isn't it the case that p1() and p2() exist in the global (i.e., window) scope? I thought that calling window.p1() is synonymous with calling p1(), just like calling alert() is synonymous with window.alert().

To my (C#) way of thinking, p1() and p2() are in the global scope. These functions are members of the global window object so when they refer to "this" they should be referring to [object Window]. Obviously, I'm very wrong here.

Comment: looks like you are running the script in strict mode

Comment: runs fine on Chrome console.. I get `[object Window]` for all the alerts!

Comment: the issue is strict mode. running the code you've put here does as you'd expect and alerts window for all alerts

Comment: see the second para in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm using `use strict` and it works fine, albeit on Chrome console. Does the console neglect it??

Comment: when I try this in firefox with strict mode in the console I get `undefined`. However chomre does appear to be alerting `window`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/287rvmkc/1/ & http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/287rvmkc/2/

Comment: also read - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @All - Yes, I am running in strict mode.

Comment: @EdCottrell: That's not a duplicate of that question (I know, because I created the linked one)

Comment: @TomBaxter so there is your answer

Comment: just updated my answer Re: chrome giving window in stead of undefined, seems it works find in a sef rather then entered into the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm running this on console, `'use strict'
alert(this); // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay

function p1() {
    //console.log('p1', this);
     alert(this);
}

var p2 = function () {
   // console.log('p2', this);
   alert(this);
}

p1(); // alerts as undefined  -- ???
p2(); // alerts as undefined  -- ??
window.p1(); // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay
window.p2(); // alerts as [object Window] -- Okay`

doesn't alert "undefined", but on fiddler, it does

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677452/possible-to-enable-strict-mode-in-firebug-and-chromes-console & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369328/how-to-use-strict-mode-in-chrome-javascript-console

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for those links.

Answer (score 3):

Becasue you are using `strict mode` and as per the spec:

> If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the this value is not coerced to an object.

The code you have **does** `alert` `window` in all instances of alert, but because you are in strict mode, it is `undefined` (as it should be)

UPDATE: chrome dev tools alerts `window` not `undefined`, however if you wrap it in a self executing function you get `undefined` as expected

```
(function(){
   'use strict';
   alert(this);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I agree on chrome console (dev tools) it doesn't alert "undefined". Got me confused!

Comment: it confused me to, strange that firefox used the 'use strict' from putting it in the console but chome required a wrapper

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function like `foo()`, then the value of `this` depends on whether the code runs in [**strict mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or not (the default actually).

In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined` (as you already found out).

In "loose mode" `this` will indeed refer to `window`, but that's **not** because the functions are global, i.e. "owned" by the global scope. You get the same behavior for local functions:

```js
(function() {
  function foo() {
    console.log(this); // logs the window object, but `foo` is not global
  }
  foo();
}());
```

This is simply an [explicitly defined behavior](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3):

> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).
>      ...

As you can see, in "loose" mode, if `thisArg` is `undefined`, which is the case if you call the function "normally" as `foo()`, then it will be set to `window` *explicitly*.

Comment: This is simply a duplicate :)

Comment: @Kitler: Of which question? Also, even it is a duplicate, it doesn't invalidate my answer.

Comment: Of every scope question to date? You even have a detailed canonical about them....

Comment: @Kitler: If you refer to the question that is currently claimed to be a duplicate, then, well, it's not. The linked question is about `this`, yes, but it is about a different issue.

Comment: @Kitler not really.. they mostly explains about `call/apply/bind` not about strict mode

Answer (score 0):

`this` is what denotes you are referring to that object you are. It is mostly used in Object Oriented Programming to differentiate between an object's self versus input variables.

Example (pseudo code):

`var1 //instance variable of object
 void Constructor(var1){
     this.var1 = var1
 }`

What this describes is the constructor takes in a var called `var1`, and sets it's own variable `var1` to it.

In your case, I would assume that when in a function:

`function p1() {
    alert(this);
}`

being called as `p1();`, it is not strictly in an object context, therefore `this` does not mean anything. By calling it from the window's context `window.p1();`, you are making the window object call the function, therefore giving `this` a value.

Comment: sorry but thats incorrect. the issue is cause by strict mode. in the examples p1() and window.p1() are the same thing, strict mode is whats effecting the value of `this`